# Cannot copy or paste commands in labs.play-with-kubernetes free intance

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to copy and paste few commands inside the labs.play-with-k8s free instance provided by kubernetes. Both the commands the Ctrl+c and Ctrl+v doesn't work.

I found few options like ctrl + shift +insert to copy but that also doesn't seems to work for me.

Any suggestion please.

Comment: Please don't screenshots, they are not accessible.

Comment: I am not able to add the screenshots to this post. please check https://labs.play-with-k8s.com/

Answer (score 20):

ctrl + insert to copy and shift + insert to paste

Comment: amazing. I dont have insert key on my laptop

Answer (score 3):

The terminal experience is the same with the [labs.play-with-docker](https://labs.play-with-docker.com/)

You can copy/paste with `Ctrl+Shift+c/v`

Comment: you cant because some browsers use `Ctrl+Shift+C` for the browsers console

Comment: Can't work with Chrome at least. It would open its console.

Answer (score 3):

on windows with MS-Edge browser following cmd will work

COPY with  ctrl+Insert+ c
Paste with  ctrl+SHift+v

Answer (score 1):

Solution that worked for me:
Windows, Chrome, Edge:
I copied using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>INSERT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in Edge
Then pasted using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If in Windows, use Mozilla. You can copy selecting text with right click. And to paste use Shift + INS key.

Answer (score 0):

Please change none to Mac OSX in the instance settings.

Answer (score 0):

[In the versions after 5.3](https://github.com/lensapp/lens/pull/3904) you can enable "copy on select and right-click to paste" which is the most efficient imho. Find the option on File-->Preferences-->terminal:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

COPY -> CTRL+INSERT or CTRL+FN+INSERT

PASTE -> SHIFT+CTRL+V